# My Mac has no recovery partition to boot from

Tags: imac, filesystem-corruption, macos-sierra, boot-partition

On my late 2009 iMac, Disk Utility tells me my internal HDD is corrupted, and to boot from the recovery partition to repair it. I am running the system off the external HDD right now and holding <kbd>option</kbd> at start has no result. How do I get back to a working state?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably holding Opt shows the external HD to boot from, just nothing for the internal. In which case, once you're booted from it, you can do all the work from the external.

Recovery is really only necessary if you have nothing else you can boot from, [or to change the state of SIP, but that's not relevant to this issue]